# reading a datafile to array/list

Tags: python-2.7

Aim: Reading a data file(numerical values), creating array/list 
Problems: each digits are formed as array, instead I need the whole value as one array/list

Input data file (1.txt) : 2 columns are separated by a tab gap

0.85787         0.8E-03

0.8578          45.8E-03

0.857878        5.8E-03

0.657878        2.3E-03

.....           ......

```
crs = open("1.txt","r")
for line in crs:
 x = line.split()
 k=str(x[0]) # string to avoid spacing problem
 v=str(x[1])
 print k[0]
```

k[0] lists ONLY the first digits ie.,

0

0

0

0

0

but my requirements are to store 0.85787 in k[0] .... 0.657878 in k[3] ....

and 0.8E-03 in v[0] ...... 2.3E-03 in v[3] .... and use it further, importantly NO empty spaces/gaps.

Please suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create separate lists for the two columns of your data the simplest way is to simply create the lists before you start the loop, then append to them as you loop through the file:

```
k = []
v = []
with open("1.txt", "r") as crs:
    for line in crs:
        x = line.split()
        k.append(x[0]) # use float(x[0]) if you want numbers rather than strings
        v.append(x[1])
```

A more "Pythonic" (but perhaps more difficult to understand) solution is to use a generator expression and the `zip` function to create the two lists simultaneously:

```
with open("1.txt", "r") as crs:
    k, v = zip(*(line.split() for line in crs))
```